# Adding Smush.it to my image resizing script

Tags: php, pagespeed, lossless-compression

Here's a PHP snippet from my class called 'Image'.

Here is the full function inside my class

```
protected function _output( $save_in = null, $quality, $filters = null ) {
  switch ($this->_mime_type) {
    case self::IMAGETYPE_JPEG :
    case self::IMAGETYPE_JPG :
      return imagejpeg ( $this->_image, $save_in, 65 );
      break;
    default :
      trigger_error ( 'Image cannot be created.', E_USER_NOTICE );
      break;
  } // end switch
} // end method
```

I want to then use Smush.it to compress this newly resized image before I save the modified file.

I found this code line at [GitHub GhislainPhu/php-lib-smushit](https://github.com/GhislainPhu/php-lib-smushit), but I'm not sure how to call this class within my own class.

```
$smushit = new SmushIt('/path/to/myimage.jpg');
```

Can anyone help me? This will help so much with page speed.

Comment: Yes, of course, but to use Smush.it, it's a class, so how would I go about passing my $this->_image into the SmushIt class?

Comment: You wrote in your very question how to do it...Initialize the class passing it the file name/path

Comment: I should've clarified, my PHP line is a snippet from inside another class called 'Image'. I've added my full function above. Thank you!